# How to trim down a Pandas data frame rows?

Tags: python

I'm trying so hard to shorten this awful lot of rows from an XML sitemap but I can't find a solution to trim it down.

```
import advertools as adv
import pandas as pd

site = "https://www.halfords.com/sitemap_index.xml"

sitemap = adv.sitemap_to_df(site)
sitemap = sitemap.dropna(subset=["loc"]).reset_index(drop=True)

    # Some sitemaps keeps urls with "/" on the end, some is with no "/"
    # If there is "/" on the end, we take the second last column as slugs
    # Else, the last column is the slug column
slugs = sitemap['loc'].dropna()[~sitemap['loc'].dropna().str.endswith('/')].str.split('/').str[-2].str.replace('-', ' ')
slugs2 = sitemap['loc'].dropna()[~sitemap['loc'].dropna().str.endswith('/')].str.split('/').str[-1].str.replace('-', ' ')

    # Merge two series
slugs = list(slugs) + list(slugs2)

    # adv.word_frequency automatically removes the stop words
word_counts_onegram = adv.word_frequency(slugs)
word_counts_twogram = adv.word_frequency(slugs, phrase_len=2)

competitor = pd.concat([word_counts_onegram, word_counts_twogram])\
.rename({'abs_freq':'Count','word':'Ngram'}, axis=1)\
.sort_values('Count', ascending=False)

competitor.to_csv('competitor.csv',index=False)
competitor
```

[image]

competitor.shape
(67758, 2)

```
(67758, 2)
```

I've been raveling around several blogs included resources on Stack Overflow but nothing seemed to work.
This is definitely something going on with my zero expertise in coding I suppose

Comment: Can you describe more clearly exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't want to print 67758 rows but possibly only 100 in a Pandas data frame

Comment: Very large number of results with phrase_len=2. You need to understand what you want to get and use the right parameters. https://advertools.readthedocs.io/en/master/advertools.word_frequency.html?highlight=word_frequency#

Comment: Wait, are you just looking for `competitor.head(100)`??

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You can use `adv.url_to_df` to split URLs and get the slugs (there should be a column called `last_dir`:

```py
urldf = adv.url_to_df(sitemap['loc'].dropna())
urldf
```

|  | url | scheme | netloc | path | query | fragment | dir_1 | dir_2 | dir_3 | dir_4 | dir_5 | dir_6 | dir_7 | dir_8 | dir_9 | last_dir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | https://www.halfords.com/cycling/cycling-technology/helmet-cameras/removu-k1-4k-camera-and-stabiliser-694977.html | https | [www.halfords.com](http://www.halfords.com) | /cycling/cycling-technology/helmet-cameras/removu-k1-4k-camera-and-stabiliser-694977.html | nan | nan | cycling | cycling-technology | helmet-cameras | removu-k1-4k-camera-and-stabiliser-694977.html | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | removu-k1-4k-camera-and-stabiliser-694977.html |
| 1 | https://www.halfords.com/technology/bluetooth-car-kits/jabra-drive-bluetooth-speakerphone---white-695094.html | https | [www.halfords.com](http://www.halfords.com) | /technology/bluetooth-car-kits/jabra-drive-bluetooth-speakerphone---white-695094.html | nan | nan | technology | bluetooth-car-kits | jabra-drive-bluetooth-speakerphone---white-695094.html | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | jabra-drive-bluetooth-speakerphone---white-695094.html |
| 2 | https://www.halfords.com/tools/power-tools-and-accessories/power-tools/stanley-fatmax-v20-18v-combi-drill-kit-695102.html | https | [www.halfords.com](http://www.halfords.com) | /tools/power-tools-and-accessories/power-tools/stanley-fatmax-v20-18v-combi-drill-kit-695102.html | nan | nan | tools | power-tools-and-accessories | power-tools | stanley-fatmax-v20-18v-combi-drill-kit-695102.html | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | stanley-fatmax-v20-18v-combi-drill-kit-695102.html |
| 3 | https://www.halfords.com/technology/dash-cams/mio-mivue-c450-695262.html | https | [www.halfords.com](http://www.halfords.com) | /technology/dash-cams/mio-mivue-c450-695262.html | nan | nan | technology | dash-cams | mio-mivue-c450-695262.html | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | mio-mivue-c450-695262.html |
| 4 | https://www.halfords.com/technology/dash-cams/mio-mivue-818-695270.html | https | [www.halfords.com](http://www.halfords.com) | /technology/dash-cams/mio-mivue-818-695270.html | nan | nan | technology | dash-cams | mio-mivue-818-695270.html | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | mio-mivue-818-695270.html |

2. There are options that pandas provides, which you can change. For example:

```py
pd.options.display.max_rows
60

# change it to display more/fewer rows:

pd.options.display.max_rows = 100
```

As you did, you can easily create onegrams and bigrams, combine them, and display them:

```py
text_list = urldf['last_dir'].str.replace('-', ' ').dropna()

one_grams = adv.word_frequency(text_list, phrase_len=1)
bigrams = adv.word_frequency(text_list, phrase_len=2)

print(pd.concat([one_grams, bigrams])
 .sort_values('abs_freq', ascending=False)
 .head(15) # <-- change this to 100 for example
 .reset_index(drop=True))
```

|  | word | abs_freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | halfords | 2985 |
| 1 | car | 1430 |
| 2 | bike | 922 |
| 3 | kit | 829 |
| 4 | black | 777 |
| 5 | laser | 686 |
| 6 | set | 614 |
| 7 | wheel | 540 |
| 8 | pack | 524 |
| 9 | mats | 511 |
| 10 | car mats | 478 |
| 11 | thule | 453 |
| 12 | paint | 419 |
| 13 | 4 | 413 |
| 14 | spray | 382 |

Hope that helps?